# Show that $\dim(V) \geq 2k$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$

(i) Suppose that $v_1\ldots v_k$ is a list of vectors in $V$. Explain what we mean by $\operatorname{span}(v_1\ldots v_k)$

(ii) Let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear map and $(v_1\ldots v_k) \in V$. Suppose that $(T(v_1),T(v_2),\ldots,T(v_k))$ is a linearly independent $k$-tuple in $V$. Show that ($v_1\ldots v_k$) is a linearly independent $k$-tuple in $V$

(iii)  Under the assumption of part (ii), suppose also that $T\circ T  = 0$ (that is, $T$ composed with itself is the zero map). Show that $\dim(V) \geq 2k.$

I have completed parts (i) and (ii), however I am stuck on part (iii). I am guessing that we have to use the rank nullity theorem here, i.e use the property that $\dim(V) = \operatorname{rank}(T) + \operatorname{null}(T)$. But I'm not quite sure how to start. Could someone please give me a small nudge in the right direction?

Comment: Are you sure the inequality is in the right direction?

Comment: The inequality is in the wrong direction. Consider $\Bbb{R}^6$, with standard basis $(e_i)_{i=1}^6$, and let $T(e_1)=e_3$, $T(e_2)=e_4$, $T(e_i)=0$ for $3\leq i\leq 6$. Then $\{e_1, e_2\}$ is linearly independent, as is $\{T(e_1), T(e_2)\}$, and $\mathrm{dim}(\Bbb{R}^6)=6$.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! Have edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the statement $\mathrm{dim}(V)\leq 2k$ is incorrect, I will prove what I assume to be what you meant, that $\mathrm{dim}(V)\geq 2k$.
Note that the image of $T$, $T(V)$, contains $k$ linearly independent vectors, and therefore has dimension $\geq k$ by basic linear algebra. Since $\mathrm{rank}(T)=\mathrm{dim}(T(V))$, we have $\mathrm{rank}(T)\geq k$. Similarly, note that, since $T(T(V))=0$, $T(V)\subseteq\mathrm{nspc}(T)$, where $\mathrm{nspc}$ refers to the null space/kernel of a linear transformation, and therefore, $\mathrm{null}(T)=\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{nspc}(T))\geq k$, again, by basic linear algebra.

By the rank nullity theorem, we therefore get that $\mathrm{dim}(V)\geq 2k$.

Comment: I see that the direction of the inequality in the Q has been reversed and now conforms with  this A.